# NOT operator problem in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create an SQL command in a MySQL/PHP environment where the *NOT* operator is used. 
I have created the following piece of code:

```
"SELECT software.*, FROM software,softwarever WHERE  
software.ID = softwarever.ID AND (software.ID='$_GET[text]' OR
software.Name='$_GET[text]') 
NOT(software.ID='$_GET[extra_text]' OR software.Name='$_GET[extra_text]')";
```

When I go and execute it however it gives me error due to the *NOT* operator. Does anyone knows if there is a solution to this? 
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I don't want the *NOT IN* operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put and AND or OR before your NOT, depending on your logic.  And lose the comma after your SELECT.  For exmaple:

```
"
SELECT software.*
FROM   software,softwarever 
WHERE  software.ID = softwarever.ID 
AND    (software.ID='$_GET[text]' OR software.Name='$_GET[text]') 
OR NOT (software.ID='$_GET[extra_text]' OR software.Name='$_GET[extra_text]')
";
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing AND/OR before the NOT.

The query doesn't know if you want X AND NOT Y or X OR NOT Y